# .htaccess and environment variables

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to have environment variables in a htaccess file for cakephp?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase    /~username/project
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But instead of username I would like to have the environment variable USER?  Something like this but it doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase    /~%{ENV:USER}/project
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have activated mod_env in Apache?

Comment: I don't think so.  Is there a way to set it from command line?  And is there any negatives from having mod_env enabled?

Comment: You need to edit httpd.conf file and restart apache.